# How to display the date and time when the html page is sent as an E-Mail

Tags: html, email, dom, html-email

I have configured send mail and able to send all mails to any number of users.
Now we have a cronjob running which starts the server every sunday at 2:00 AM. This cronjob will call my script for a restart. I ave created a html page which dynamically picks the time and the day and send it as an e-mail in html format. However on the mail the dates and the day is not getting dispalyed.

Any ideas how to get this working???

```
**My Code**

To: user1@gmail.com
Subject: Application Server Status on host
Content-Type: text/html; charset="us-ascii"

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Gerrit Server Status</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>
        <marquee behavior="scroll" bgcolor="yellow" loop="-1" width="30%">
            <i>
               <font color="blue">
                 Application Server status :
                 <strong>
                  <span id="time"></span>
                 </strong>
               </font>
            </i>
         </marquee>
         <br>
         <font color="blue">
         Application Server was restarted and the services are up and running.
    </p>
<script>
    var today = new Date;
    document.getElementById('time').innerHTML= today.toDateString();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The E-Mail that i received has the following data:

```
Application Server status : 
Application Server was restarted and the services are up and running.
```

On the actual HTML page it displays he date and time as expected.

Any leads as to why on the e-mail the date and time is not getting displayed???

Thank you,
Anish

Answer (score 0):

generally speaking email clients will not run javascript.  What are you using on the backend? php? if php try this:

```
<span id="time"><?php echo today.toDateString(); ?> </span>
```

Comment: No Backend, plane an simple html code. 
It is a cronjob which is triggering the script for a service restart and post the script success or failure it simply send a mail using the sendmail the contents of which is in the html format